# Uso adecuado de Corrutinas en Kotlin: ¿Global Scope es la mejor opción?

Tags: kotlin, scope, corrutinas, android-corrutinas

¿Alguien sabe cómo trabajar adecuadamente las corrutinas?

Por lo que vi en internet usar el GlobalScope no es muy recomendable y bueno, en mi app funciona todo bien hasta que la dejo en 2do plano. Básicamente para lo único que la estoy usando es para cargar información de    varios Recycler View (la información viene de una API), se ve más o menos así :

```
   GlobalScope.async {
        // API Request                  
        getStores()
        suspend {
            // Show Progress Bar
            stores_progress_bar.showProgressBar()
            delay(3500 )
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // Recycler View
                setUpRecyclerView(view)
                // Hide Progress Bar
                stores_progress_bar.hideProgressBar()
            }
        }.invoke()
    }
```

Pd. El problema que recibo es:
not attached to a context.at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:805)

Eso sucede cuando pongo la app en segundo plano, por lo que quiero saber cómo puedo implementar correctamente las corrutinas y los ciclos de vida de mi aplicación con la finalidad de no dejar hilos sin poder detener. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema al crear coroutines por medio de `GlobalScope` es que les das un ciclo de vida equivalente al ciclo de vida de la aplicación. Es decir, se liberará/detendrá hasta que cierres la app.

Para crear coroutines correctamente depende del contexto o caso de uso que tengas. Si estás dentro de un Activity o dentro de un Fragment, puedes usar el `lifecycleScope` o dentro de un ViewModel puedes usar el `viewModelScope`:

**Activity:**

```
lifecycleScope.launch { 
    ...
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    ...
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
viewModelScope.launch { 
    ...
}
```

En el caso del Activity y del Fragment no debes preocuparte por detener sus CoroutineScopes ya que `lifecycleScope` es consciente del ciclo de vida. Igualmente el `viewModelScope` es consciente del ciclo de vida del ViewModel.

Si lo quieres hacer dentro de una clase normal debes implementar la intefaz `CoroutineScope` y asegurarte de cancelar el `Job` o el CoroutineScope mismo cuando lo requieras:

```
class MyClass: CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Default

    fun myFunction() {
        launch {
            ...
        }
    }
    
    fun release() {
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```